# How can I get smooth transitions on nested sliders using AnythingSlider?

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

I'm trying to create nested sliders using AnythingSlider, and I'm coming across an issue. Going forward, the slides transition fine. However, going back, once the slide containing the nested slider is reached, the slide shifts awkwardly from right to left into place.

Here is an example of what I'm experiencing: http://jsfiddle.net/S8Je5/118/ -- there is a clear difference between the forward and back transitions with respect to the nested slider slide.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, ok, so it's showing a flash of the first cloned panel of the nested slider. What I had to do was restyle the cloned panel content to resemble the first real nested slide. (I was able to see how the cloned panel looked by setting the position of the outer slider to 0 using Firebug). Here is the fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/S8Je5/146/

Answer (score 0):

This still has a few quirks and is kind of hacky, but the transitions looks much better.

Step 1: Move the #slider2 jquery ABOVE the #slider jquery

Step 2: `<center>` your inner ul (slider2)

Here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/S8Je5/119/

The quirkiness is that sometimes it appears to display a blank image in the inside slider.

In Chrome, you can fix that by placing an img tag inside the inner ul with style float: left

Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/S8Je5/120/

This works well in Chrome, not sure about other browsers, but its a good start.

Comment: Thanks for this, however switching the order of the declarations didn't fix anything on my non-test version.

Comment: Whoops, just noticed my answer was missing the word 'center' because it wasn't in a code tag.  That's really the important part.  I noticed your solution doesn't show the forward/back buttons during transition, but... as long as you're happy with it, glad it's fixed!